# ALPHA_8 bitmaps and getPixel

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to load a movement map from a PNG image. In order to save memory
 after I load the bitmap I do something like that.

```
 
 `Bitmap mapBmp = tempBmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8, false);`
```

If I draw the mapBmp I can see the map but when I use getPixel() I get 
 always 0 (zero).

Is there a way to retrieve ALPHA information from a bitmap other than
 with getPixel() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a nice and sort of clean way to create boundary maps. I create an ALPHA_8 bitmap from the start. I **paint my boundry map with paths**. Then I use the **copyPixelsToBuffer()** and transfer the bytes into a **ByteBuffer**. I use the buffer to "getPixels" from. 
I think is a good solution since you can scale down or up the path() and draw the boundary map at the desired screen resolution scale and no IO + decode operations.
Bitmap.getPixel() is useless for ALPHA_8 bitmaps, it always returns 0.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how can I extract the "pixels" of an `ALPHA_8` `Bitmap`? I'm always getting 0...

Answer (score 5):

Seems to be an Android bug in handling `ALPHA_8`. I also tried `copyPixelsToBuffer`, to no avail. Simplest workaround is to waste lots of memory and use `ARGB_8888`.

[Issue 25690](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25690)

Answer (score 2):

I found this question from Google and I was able to extract the pixels using the [copyPixelsToBuffer()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copyPixelsToBuffer%28java.nio.Buffer%29) method that Mitrescu Catalin ended up using. This is what my code looks like in case anyone else finds this as well:

```
public byte[] getPixels(Bitmap b) {
    int bytes = b.getRowBytes() * b.getHeight();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes);
    b.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
    return buffer.array();
}
```

If you are coding for API level 12 or higher you could use [getByteCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getByteCount%28%29) instead to get the total number of bytes to allocate. However if you are coding for API level 19 (KitKat) you should probably use [getAllocationByteCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getAllocationByteCount%28%29) instead.

Comment: Even copyPixelsToBuffer() is giving zeros in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I developed solution with PNGJ library, to read image from assets and then create Bitmap with Config.ALPHA_8.

```
import ar.com.hjg.pngj.IImageLine;
import ar.com.hjg.pngj.ImageLineHelper;
import ar.com.hjg.pngj.PngReader;

public Bitmap getAlpha8BitmapFromAssets(String file) {

    Bitmap result = null;

    try {

        PngReader pngr = new PngReader(getAssets().open(file));
        int channels = pngr.imgInfo.channels;
        if (channels < 3 || pngr.imgInfo.bitDepth != 8)
            throw new RuntimeException("This method is for RGB8/RGBA8 images");

        int bytes = pngr.imgInfo.cols * pngr.imgInfo.rows;
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes);

        for (int row = 0; row < pngr.imgInfo.rows; row++) { 

            IImageLine l1 = pngr.readRow();

            for (int j = 0; j < pngr.imgInfo.cols; j++) {

                int original_color = ImageLineHelper.getPixelARGB8(l1, j);

                byte x = (byte) Color.alpha(original_color);

                buffer.put(row * pngr.imgInfo.cols + j, x ^= 0xff);

            }

        }

        pngr.end();

        result = Bitmap.createBitmap(pngr.imgInfo.cols,pngr.imgInfo.rows, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
        result.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
    }

    return result;

}
```

I also invert alpha values, because of my particular needs. This code is only tested for API 21.