# Unable to retrieve and set pixels

Tags: android, bitmap

I am attempting to set the pixel values of an ALPHA_8 bitmap directly, and find that I am unable to set any pixels.

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(2, 2, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
b.setPixel(0, 0, Color.TRANSPARENT);
b.setPixel(1, 0, Color.WHITE);
System.out.println("0, 0 is " + b.getPixel(0, 0)); // 0, 0 is 0
System.out.println("1, 0 is " + b.getPixel(1, 0)); // 1, 0 is 0
```

Is there a way to be able to get and set pixel values on an ALPHA_8 bitmap?

Comment: seems to be a bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247369/alpha-8-bitmaps-and-getpixel