# Pixel perfect collision with Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8

Tags: java, android

I've found this code of pixel perfect collision checking and used it in my code:

```
public boolean isCollisionDetected(
    Bitmap bitmap1, int x1, int y1,
    Bitmap bitmap2, int x2, int y2
) {
    Rect bounds1 = new Rect(
        x1, y1, x1 + bitmap1.getWidth(), y1 + bitmap1.getHeight()
    );
    Rect bounds2 = new Rect(
        x2, y2, x2 + bitmap2.getWidth(), y2 + bitmap2.getHeight()
    );

    if (Rect.intersects(bounds1, bounds2)) {
        Rect collisionBounds = getCollisionBounds(bounds1, bounds2);
        for (int i = collisionBounds.left; i < collisionBounds.right; i++) {
            for (int j = collisionBounds.top; j < collisionBounds.bottom; j++) {
                int bitmap1Pixel = bitmap1.getPixel(i - x1, j - y1);
                int bitmap2Pixel = bitmap2.getPixel(i - x2, j - y2);
                if (isFilled(bitmap1Pixel) && isFilled(bitmap2Pixel)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private Rect getCollisionBounds(Rect rect1, Rect rect2) {
    int left = (int) Math.max(rect1.left, rect2.left);
    int top = (int) Math.max(rect1.top, rect2.top);
    int right = (int) Math.min(rect1.right, rect2.right);
    int bottom = (int) Math.min(rect1.bottom, rect2.bottom);
    return new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);
}

private boolean isFilled(int pixel) {
    return pixel != Color.TRANSPARENT;
}
```

And it worked perfectly, no problems what so ever. That until I set the images into [`Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config#ALPHA_8) using this code (because of RAM problems):

```
private Bitmap convert(Bitmap bitmap, Bitmap.Config config) {
    Bitmap convertedBitmap = 
        Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), config);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(convertedBitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
    return convertedBitmap;
}
```

Why Nothing won't happen, it does go inside `isCollisionDetected`, I've checked with logs! But it won't detect collision... Can anyone provide working function for checking pixel perfect collision of Bitmap with `Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling [`getPixel()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap?hl=en#getPixel(int,%20int)) on a Bitmap with `ALPHA_8` configuration will always return zero. This seems to be [a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247369/alpha-8-bitmaps-and-getpixel).

You can work around this problem by storing the pixels of each Bitmap as a byte array:

```
byte[] pixelData = getPixels(convert(bitmap, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8));

...

public byte[] getPixels(Bitmap bmp) {
    int bytes = bmp.getRowBytes() * bmp.getHeight();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes);
    bmp.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
    return buffer.array();
}
```

You will need to modify your collision detection function a little:

```
public boolean isCollisionDetected(
    byte[] pixels1, Bitmap bitmap1, int x1, int y1,
    byte[] pixels2, Bitmap bitmap2, int x2, int y2
) {
    Rect bounds1 = new Rect(
        x1, y1, x1 + bitmap1.getWidth(), y1 + bitmap1.getHeight()
    );
    Rect bounds2 = new Rect(
        x2, y2, x2 + bitmap2.getWidth(), y2 + bitmap2.getHeight()
    );

    if (Rect.intersects(bounds1, bounds2)) {
        Rect collisionBounds = getCollisionBounds(bounds1, bounds2);
        for (int i = collisionBounds.left; i < collisionBounds.right; i++) {
            for (int j = collisionBounds.top; j < collisionBounds.bottom; j++) {
                byte bitmap1Pixel = pixels1[((j - y1) * width1) + (i - x1)];
                byte bitmap2Pixel = pixels2[((j - y2) * width2) + (i - x2)];
                if (isFilled(bitmap1Pixel) && isFilled(bitmap2Pixel)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't affect the bitmap for some reason, it does nothing, doesn't color it black, and if i use it and use the convert as well there is still no collision. And yes I do apply it to new bitmaps loaded   this.coin = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
    R.drawable.item_coin,options);

Comment: when I convert bitmap to alpha_8 they turn black, when I used this code nothing changed to the bitmaps, meaning they still take the same amount of ram as before, no?

Comment: They should use less. (1byte per pixel). We could try to resolve this per chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73375/android-pixel-perfect-collision

Comment: Works! thank you so much. There is only one thing that is weird, first the garbage collector wont stop calling, like logcat is being spammed with it all the sudden, secondly it wont let me recycle all the sudden the bitmap I converted, it says canvas cannot draw recycled bitmap but I don't use that bitmap anymore so its really weird.

Comment: I don't know about your recycling problem, but removing allocations from frequently called methods should calm the gc down; if your problems persist, consider opening a new question respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Android Config_Alpha_8  does not save color information, so when you draw the bitmap, adding the paint will do nothing, and all isFilled checks will return false.

Neat piece of code though.

Comment: I understand the problem, but there needs to be solution. The pixels are being displayed on the screen, so there needs to be a way getting their position, and from there a collision checking should be possible.