# ByteBuffer=Garbage collector spam

Tags: java, android, bitmap, garbage-collection

Few days ago I was given a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29061657/4024143) of checking collision between two bitmaps that has config_alpha_8. But upon using it I noticed my app started lagging oddly, and when I checked the logs I noticed the garbage collector was spamming every millisecond

[image]

I tried removing few lines, and found out what causing the garbage collector going hype sh*t were these lines:

```
byte[] pixelData = getPixels(bitmap1);
byte[] pixelData2 = getPixels(bitmap2);
```

which called this function:

```
public byte[] getPixels(Bitmap bmp) {
  int bytes = bmp.getRowBytes() * bmp.getHeight();
  ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes);
  bmp.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
  return buffer.array();
}
```

Why? What can I do to make it stop?

Comment: What are you trying to stop.  The allocation or the GC_FOR_ALLOC log message?

Comment: @StephenC both I guess, I dont care about the messages, I care about the fact the garbage collector keeps being called none-stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allocating large contiguous blocks of memory (i.e. a `byte[]`). Depending on how large your images are, this could be accounting for a significant amount of your available heap.
If you are going to be doing a lot of these type of operations, it may be worth considering pooling `byte[]` instances of fixed sizes to be reused.

Comment: However, beware that an object pool that is implemented without sufficient understanding could easily make things worse.  As in OOMEs.

Comment: @StephenC Uhm, so could you please help me? I'm not very good with pools.

Comment: @SpoocyCrep consider using commons-pool as the basis of managing your pools. You actually need to manage multiple pools, one for each `byte[]` size you need. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/

Comment: @BrettOkken instead of using pool I just created an hashmap with bitmap and its bytes in the beginning.