# get in Hashmap returns null

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I have a basic Hashmap code that wont work for some reason.

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Bitmap, byte[]> pixels = new ConcurrentHashMap<Bitmap, byte[]>();
```

it key is bitmap, and the value are its bytes that I get using this code:

```
public byte[] getPixels(Bitmap bmp) {
    int bytes = bmp.getRowBytes() * bmp.getHeight();
 buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bytes);
    bmp.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
    buffer.clear();
    return buffer.array();
}
```

In the hashmap for all the bitmaps I have I put:

```
    pixels.put(bitmap1, getPixels(b));
```

And when I want to get the value (bytes) back I do:

```
    byte[] pixelData = pixels.get(bitmap1);
```

and for some odd reason its always null!, why? I tried on different bitmaps, they all return null, and it is the same bitmap..

Comment: Erm... You can't call `.array()` on a directly allocated `ByteBuffer`. There's something else going on.

Comment: @fge I can, the code is working and worked before I used hashmap. It is part of this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29061657/4024143

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be the same instance of Bitmap. If you create another instance of same Bitmap, it'll not be the same object.

For instance:

```
Bitmap b1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("mybitmap.png");
ConcurrentHashMap<Bitmap, byte[]> pixels = new ConcurrentHashMap<Bitmap, byte[]>();
pixels.add(b1);
[...]
Bitmap b2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("mybitmap.png");
byte[] barray1 = pixels.get(b1);
byte[] barray2 = pixels.get(b2);
```

barray1 is not null

barray2 is null

Comment: and if I say b2=b1; and give b2 will it return null? because thats how it is in my code,I don't have new decoded files, I use the same bitmaps.

Comment: @SpoocyCrep, If bitmap is not "recreate" (new instance or coy from BitmapFactory or Bitmap) it have to work

Comment: You're right, I've found my mistake - I rescaled the bitmap after inserting it to the hashmap without noticing. I've added it after the rescale and it works.

Answer (score 1):

First things: the javadoc of Android's `Bitmap` makes no guarantee that it supports `equals()` and `hashCode()` if they have the same content, which means that if they don't, you're screwed.

Second: [the javadoc of `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocateDirect-int-) states that:

> Whether or not it has a backing array is unspecified.

Therefore --> don't use that, use `ByteBuffer.allocate()` instead which is *guaranteed* to have a backing array.

But I guess the problem is with the first point.

Comment: Okay, I changed it to allocate but the problem stays the same. I don't say two different bitmaps with same content, the bitmaps are all pointing at the same bitmap, on create I load some bitmaps and send them to classes. I do not change the bitmap so its really weird..

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use a `HashMap` and you treat a certain type of object as a *key*, you need to consider whether that object's `equals()` method is designed properly for custom equality checks. In most cases it is not, so you need to re-implement the `equals()` method.

The prevailing logic in Java is that when you override `equals()`, you must also override the `hashCode()` method. (See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java))

In other words, you need to derive a class `CustomBitmap` from `Bitmap` and add new implementations of `equals()` and `hashCode()` to the new class. Then it can be used successfully as a key in a `HashMap`.